# Angular 9 (running with --proxy-config) POST returns 301, then OPTIONS, then GET no POST body sent to server

Tags: php, angular, http, proxy

I'm running a local angular 9 client in dev mode and attempting to post to a backend PHP resource.  Initially, I was getting CORS problems, so in the PHP file, I added:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token");
```

and also started using a proxy on the client side:

```
{
    "/awana-record-keeping/server/*": {
        "target": "http://bridgewaycc.org/site",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

The CORS errors went away in the Chrome console.  However, now I see the following sequence of network calls:

http://stevewarsa.com/all-calls.png

First there is a POST call, which results in a 301 response code (which I believe is coming from the local angular proxy):

http://stevewarsa.com/first-call.png

Second there is a GET call, which does not send a request payload and which results in a 200 response code:

http://stevewarsa.com/second-call.png

Third there is an OPTIONS call, which results in a 200:

http://stevewarsa.com/third-call.png

The result is that the PHP script does not receive the post data and therefore cannot return the requested data.

Note - the 3 calls shown in the network tab of Chrome are all resulting from one http post invocation in angular:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.awanaService.getClubbersByYear(<YearRange>{startYear: 2020, endYear: 2021}).subscribe(clubbers => {
      console.log("Here are the clubbers:");
      console.log(clubbers);
    });
  }
```

Here is the awanaService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { YearRange } from './year-range';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AwanaService {
  private _uri = "/awana-record-keeping/server/";

  constructor(private httpService:HttpClient) { }

  public getClubbersByYear(yearRange: YearRange) {
    return this.httpService.post<string[]>(`${this._uri}get-clubbers-by-year-range.php`, yearRange);
  }
}
```

I have used angular proxies in the past to do local development issuing http POST requests to remote servers hosting PHP, but for some reason, this time I cannot get around this issue.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: So you started using the proxy just because of the CORS issue? If so - why? If you are in control of the remote script, and can mkae it respond with the necessary headers, then there should be no need to involve a proxy.

Comment: I did add the headers to the PHP file to deal with the CORS issue

Comment: Interesting thing...  I switched to running the PHP page on the local apache server with PHP plugin.  Still using proxy, but now pointed to localhost:8080/site.  In that case, the angular proxy from localhost:4200 --> localhost:8080 works fine.